# How to access another BP actor's component in c++?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5

I am new to Unreal (switched from Unity) and still have some troubles understanding the main concepts, in this case how to access other objects and their components via c++ scriptig. I am using UE5 (but I guess solutions for UE4 should also work fine).

My Project looks as followed:

- In my scene I have an "Target" Actor (Blueprintclass) that has a self written c++ "movement" component with some public function to update its position.
- More over I have an "Experiment" BP Actor that has a "TrialProcedure" c++ component attached.

**Here is what I want to do:** I want to run the Target's movent component's update position function from this Actor's component.

I guess once I can access the Target Actor, I can use GetComponentByClass() to access the component I need and than run it's method. But how do I get access to that other actor without using blueprints? The Actor is already there so I don't want to spawn it from code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I found an solution for all who are interested. I use the unreals TActorIterator. With this one I iterated on begin play over all actors of the world and checked they name. Later on I acessed the specific component with the GetComponentByClass method.    
`// Get Target Actor
 for (TActorIterator<AActor> ActorItr(GetWorld()); ActorItr; ++ActorItr){
  if (ActorItr->GetClass()->GetFName().ToString() == "Target_C"){
   target = *ActorItr;
   break;
  }
 }
 // Get Target actors movement component
 target_movement = Cast<UMovement>(target->GetComponentByClass(UMovement::StaticClass()));`

Comment: Please put your comment as an answer so the code is readable.

Answer (score 0):

That is a sub-optimal solution. Use a collision and get the `Other Actor`, then try to cast it to your desired class if it's a collision event. If it fails, don't do anything but if it doesn't, pull a pin from that and execute your functions.

A better alternative to your current solution would be to use the [Get All Actors of Class](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/BlueprintAPI/Utilities/GetAllActorsOfClass/) function if you only have a single target. Just use the `Get (a copy)` node and you'll have your target blueprint. There's a C++ version of the function as well. If you have more than one file, then you'll have to check stuff.